# Can't upload file through carrierwave fog-aws to minio (docker-compose)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog, minio

Have error Excon::Error::Socket (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)) when try to upload file through carrierwave fog-aws to minio.

Docker compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 256m
    volumes:
      - 'minio:/var/lib/minio'
    environment:
      - "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=development"
      - "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=development"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: server /export
  rails:
    build: .
    command: bash -c 'rm -f /test/tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/test
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - minio
volumes:
  minio:
```

Carrierwave initializer

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id:     'development',
      aws_secret_access_key: 'development',
      region:                'us-east-1',
      host:                  'minio',
      endpoint:              'http://localhost:9000'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'test'
  config.fog_public     = false
  # config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Comment: maybe seeing your server log would help understanding this issue.

Comment: in the log only one error. Excon::Error::Socket (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError))

Comment: I believe that error will come up when dns can not be resolved, maybe localhost is not defined in that context? You might try explicitly setting the ip, so using endpoint value of `http://127.0.0.1:9000`.

Comment: I forgot about internal addresses in the docker. instead http://localhost:9000 i must use http://minio:9000. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Carrierwave inside docker container should point to the service DNS in your case following change should work

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id:     'development',
      aws_secret_access_key: 'development',
      region:                'us-east-1',
      host:                  'minio',
      endpoint:              'http://minio:9000'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'test'
  config.fog_public     = false
  # config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to previous answer you should also add `'path_style' => true` to your config